# SSIS processing of duplicate key SQL Server rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, duplicates

I am using SSIS to insert rows into a SQL Server table.

I notice a difference in behaviour for these two different scenarios:

1. where there are duplicate-key rows in the input
2. where existing rows have the same key as the input

In 1 SSIS raises an exception and does not process any rows.
In 2 SSIS raises an exception but does process rows.

I don't have any additional information than that. I am not trying to fix anything; just trying to understand why it behaves differently in the two scenarios.

I tried both scenarios. In cleaning up the data for scenario 1 I was left with scenario 2 (unexpectedly).